# Cloud Armor Matching rule

Tags: google-cloud-armor

My goal is to match evaluatePreconfiguredExpr('sqli-stable') except certain requestUrls.
I have setup this expression without any luck:

```
"expression": "!request.headers['host'].lower().contains('exclude/this/path') && evaluatePreconfiguredExpr('sqli-stable')
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Is [this](https://cloud.google.com/armor/docs/rules-language-reference#preconfigured_rule_examples) the sample you use for reference? There might be an excess `"` on your code. Can you send more details on your post or include the sample URL itself.

Comment: You can also try this format: `!request.path.matches(...) && evaluatePreconfiguredExpr('lfi-stable')` but looking at the documentation this feature does not exist.

Comment: The HTTP **host** header contains the domain name, not the request path.